# Grouping a set of like numbers in a Python List

Tags: python, list

I have a task that is asking me to go through a binary data set and identify clusters of 1's as a peak. As part of the conditions of the assignment, I am not able to use any other libraries and have to create a code using only basic python knowledge.

**For example**, I have a data set `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Counting the clusters of 1's means that the amount of peaks is 2.

Another example is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`. I should produce a result that says there are 3 peaks.

I'm unsure of how to approach this, and any advice would be helpful

Comment: Do you know how you would do it on paper? Start with that, then think about how to do each thing in code, and search for how to do that specific thing if you get stuck. This should be straightforward enough that you should just need a concept (aka how you'd do it on paper) and then just basic Python knowledge/tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through the data and increment `peaks` only if it hasn't already done so with each peak

```py
counted_peak = False
peaks = 0
for v in data:
    if v:
        if not counted_peak:
            peaks += 1
            # set to True so that it only increments once for each peak
            counted_peak = True
    else:
        counted_peak = False
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to solve that problem. What we do here is keep track of a counter `t` and increment it any time we see a new cluster (which happens iff we see a `1` and the last value was `0` or non-existent). Since we need to know if the last value was `0` or non-existent, we keep track of that as well in the variable `lz`.

```
def foo(L):
  t, lz = 0, 1
  for x in L:
    t, lz = t+lz*x, 1-x
  return t
```